# Display a product field value on WooCommerce admin edit order page

Tags: woocommerce, product, admin, custom-fields, orders

In WooCommerce, I have added a product custom field (a product note)  and it is displayed successfully in single product pages, under add to cart button.

How can I display that custom field value on admin order pages?

This is my field code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_note', 5 );
function custom_product_note() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { 
        echo '<br><div style="margin-top:20px;">';

        woocommerce_form_field('product_note', array(
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'class' => array( 'my-field-class form-row-wide') ,
            'label' => __('Product Note - You can add up to 15 characters.') ,
            'maxlength' => ('15'),
            'placeholder' => __('Add a product note, please.') ,
            'required' => true,
        ) , '');

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the field value when adding to cart a product:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_product_note_as_cart_item_data', 10 );
function save_product_note_as_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['product_note']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['product_note'] = esc_attr($_POST['product_note']);
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );

        // Display a message notice (optional)
        wc_add_notice( __("The product note has been saved successfully", "woocommerce"));
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Then you need to save this custom product note in the order data *(specifically in the order item as custom metadata)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_and_display_on_admin_edit_order', 10, 4 );
function save_and_display_on_admin_edit_order( $item, $item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset($values['product_note']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( '_product_note', $values['product_note'] );
    }
}

// Add readable "meta key" label name replacement
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    if( is_admin() && $item->get_type() === 'line_item' && $meta->key === '_product_note' ) {
        $display_key = __('Note', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works

[image]